# NT Authentication with GoogleHttpClient

Tags: java, authentication, windows-authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, google-http-client

#### How are you supposed to do NT Authentication using the `Google Http Client`?

I can find plenty of information for the `Apache HttpClient` and `NTCredentials` and I have that working but nothing on the Google client which I am trying to standardize new code on.

#### I have gotten this far:

```
final NTCredentials ntc = new NTCredentials(System.getProperty("user.name"), args[0], InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), "DOMAIN");
final BasicCredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
cp.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, ntc);
final HttpClientBuilder hcb = HttpClientBuilder.create();
hcb.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(cp);
final HttpTransport ht = new ApacheHttpTransport(hcb.build());
```

#### and I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:210)
    at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport.<init>(ApacheHttpTransport.java:129)
    at GoogleHttpClientScratch.main(GoogleHttpClientScratch.java:36)
```

caused by this in `org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.java`:

```
@Override
public HttpParams getParams() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ApacheHttpTransport Solution

I ended up pulling the most recent `dev` branch and [patching up the offending `ApacheHttpTransport` constructor myself](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/google-http-java-client/blob/dev/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/apache/ApacheHttpTransport.java).

I also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/pull/312) to have the changes merged into the mainline project.

I actually patched up version `1.20.0` because that is what I am using and recompiled and installed just this module in my local maven repository.

I know a better solution using `RequestConfig` exists, but this fixes up the issue for me and gets me working again *now*.

If I refactor the entire class to use `RequestConfig` I will update my fork as well. I need to read up on how `RequestConfig` is intended to be used correctly and that requires time.